# DBSCAN Clustering loop

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Using DB scan I am iterating through a csv with x, y, z, and id data. I would like to generate a new csv for a every combination of eps and minimum samples that occur within a set range.

The output csv should also include the number of points in the cluster, eps value, and minimum samples used as columns along with the original x, y, z, and id data. The code below will do this, but will only create a csv for the last cluster calculated.

```
%matplotlib notebook
from interp import *
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pdfrom sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import itertools

points_file = "examples/example-1/fcr.csv"
eps_values = np.arange(0.1,0.5,0.1)
min_samples = np.arange(5,20)
dbscan_params = list(itertools.product(eps_values, min_samples))

cluster_n = []
epsvalues = []
min_samp = []

for p in dbscan_params:
    dbscan_cluster = DBSCAN(eps=p[0], 
    min_samples=p[1]).fit(points)
    epsvalues.append(p[0])
    min_samp.append(p[1]), cluster_n.append(
len(np.unique(dbscan_cluster.labels_)))
    df = pd.read_csv(points_file, header=None, names=["x", "y", "z", "id"])
    df["cluster"] = clustering.labels_
    df["eps"] = eps
    df["min_sample"] = min_sam
    csv_name = f'fcr_{eps}e{min_sam}m.csv'
    df.to_csv(csv_name, index=False)
```

Comment: You don't seem to assign any value to `eps` and `min_sam`. Are these updated in the loop?

Comment: Yes they seem to. I think they are getting them from DBSCAN. I couldn't tell you why but min_sam reads as min_sample apparently